# How to Steam Video from iPhone to WiFi-Enabled HDTV

Tags: video, television

Just bought my first wifi-enabled HDTV.  I have a feeling this is a "duh!" question, but I can't find a clear answer.  Is it possible to stream a video from my iPhone to the HDTV?  I've heard of Chromecast, Apple TV, Roku, and various iOS apps but I'm not clear if / how any of them would do what I want.

Comment: Apple TV wil allow you to do most things you would want, but you would have to purchase it for additional costs (£100 in the UK). I don't think that's what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

If your tv can act as a DLNA client (specifically it should be a DMR - Digital Media Renderer) you should be able to do it with [ArkMC] app for iPhone[1](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/arkmc-dlna-upnp-media-streaming/id405487397?mt=8). Haven't tried it though.